# package already installed but rpm -q shows not installed

Tags: yum, rpm, rhel7

I have installed package python2-urllib3-1.10.2-7.el7.noarch on my RHEL 7.7 server using yum:

```
yum install python2-urllib3
```

and it is successfully installed.

now when I run `rpm -q python2-urllib3` it shows me the package is not installed. how to know where is the issue and fix it please.

below is a snapshot for the output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlP4t.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "issue" is in the way you're referring to the package name and the specific package you're dealing with.

When you run `yum install python2-urllib3`:

- `python2-urllib3` is not an actual package name, it is a [capability](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/ro/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch05s02s02.html)
- `python-urllib3` is the actual package name

So while you can pass a package capability to `yum`, for the `rpm` you need to pass a package name. That is why it rightfully tells you that there is no such package installed as `python2-urllib3`.

If you pass the real package name to it, as in `python-urllib3`, you will get the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

try

```sh
rpm -q python-urllib3
```

as shown in your post.

in  the  image you ran

```sh
rpm -qi python2-urllib3
```

#### note the '2' in  python2

presumably copied from the yum command in which you ran

```sh
yum install python2-urllib3
```

actual installed rpm release is

> python-urllib3-1.10.2-7.el7.noarch

#### hint

try  running

```sh
yum list installed|grep urllib3|xargs rpm -q
```

Comment: thanks, but I really mean python2-urllib3 , and I don't know why yum shows me python-urllib3 is installed, I want python2-urllib3 not python-urllib3 .

Comment: can you describe  the problem you are facing in which led you to trying to get 'python2-urllib3'? If you have python 2.7 on your system you should already have the requisite urllib  as well.

Comment: what is the output of `python -c "import  urllib3"`If  you don't get an error you should be good to go.

Comment: "I want python2-urllib3 not python-urllib3" - they are the same thing. The `python2-urllib3` is merely an alias to  `python-urllib3`. See my answer.